# How can I change android ringtone preference icon?

Tags: android, themes, preference, ringtone

I am trying to apply my custom theme in the preference screen.

I got some hint from [here](http://y-anz-m.blogspot.kr/2011/10/preferenceactivity-checkbox.html)(there are some Japanese but you can read the codes), but I don't know how to do it in ringtonepreference.

I got stuck in changing icons of ringtonepreference. I found they are @drawable/btn_circle
and @drawable/ic_btn_round_more, but couldn't find where can I override my images in theme. 
Is there any way to do it? I think there should be some way with custom theme...
Would be grateful for any advice!